# Panel size changes from computer to computer

Tags: java, swing, screen-size

I have designed a user interface for my computational software using swing (Java). I noticed that when i move the software to a laptop, the panels extends out of screen and some similar problems in nested panels. This makes it very difficult to use the software. How can I solve the problem?

Thanks.

Added: Some part of the codes follows:

```
   public GUI() {

            int width=1200;
            int height=950;
    setTitle("FEM Analysis");
    setSize(width, height);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setLocation(20, 20);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            .....}
```

Comment: What kind of layout are you using for the container that houses the panels? Some sample code would be helpful. Do the various computers you're trying it on have the same resolution, or different?

Comment: The solution is to not set any JPanel or window sizes but instead to use appropriate layout managers and let them set the preferredSizes of each component and its container.

Comment: Thanks everyone and sorry for the delay in response. The layout is border layout and the problem appears when I move to another computer with different resolution. A part of the code was added to the question setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you might want to consider (if you are not already) is using the screen dimensions to scale the size of the panels between computers with different resolutions. For example if you declared a width and height as such:

```
private final int WIDTH = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth();
private final int HEIGHT = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight();
```

Then if you multiplied the width or height by a value such as (0.8) that would give you 80% of the value.

Here's a great guide for using screen resolution: http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/java-swing-faq-how-determine-screen-size-resolution

Hope this is what you were looking for and help...

Comment: not incorrect, but usually not a good idea to set any sizes manually :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, mrbeen. Yes, that's what I was looking for. I haven't been using screen dimension to scale the size. I will correct my code and let you know the result. Thanks for the link.

Comment: the method getWidth() and getHeight() return a double not int

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using `pack()` on your GUI components. It automatically shrinks your frame to fit the content nicely instead of having a lot of blank space:

```
public GUI() {
  // ...
  pack();
}
```